# AWS - Lambda - OID - could not open relation with OID 26223345

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I am new to aws, and I have the following problem. I have a lambda configured to launch a redshift process every hour. And from time to time it fails, and in cloudwatch I detect this "could not open relation with OID 26223345". I have read about the subject, and the redshift OIDs if I can detect them with a query, but that number never appears or another that cloudwatch reports to me. is this OID from a redshift object or is it from the lambda? I would really like to know what is OID, what is happening and to be able to solve it.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

An OID is an Object ID from inside of Redshift.  Everything in Redshift has an OID.  A table has a table ID but also an OID. A database has a database ID and an OID.  A schema has an OID, so do views.  You get the idea.  So this error is says that the "thing" with OID 26223345 could not be opened.

You will want to identify what that thing is and what type of thing it is.  Likely a table but you will want to look it up.  The system table pg_class is the root reference for all OIDs and you can look up what this object (thing) is that this error is referencing there.

Comment: hello, thanks for answering. It is true that pg_class contains the ID and OID of each table, but the OID never appears.
To your question, I detect the error in cloudwatch of the lambda, which calls a redshift process. This process contains 5 processes.

Comment: The OID in question could be a temp table or other object in Redshift, or as you are implying "OID" could be a term used in some other system.  However, "could not open relation with OID 26223345" sounds like something Redshift would produce.  I suspect your Lambda is getter an error response from Redshift and echoing this out to CloudWatch.  So I don't see an inconsistency in the message ending up these logs.

Comment: That said I'd like to clarify a few things.  "This process contains 5 processes" - I assume that the first "process" is Lambda but what are these 5 other processes?  Child Lambdas?  Unique connections to Redshift (a connection to Redshift is also called a process and has a PID)?  Timing interactions between different sessions on Redshift opens up a whole different set of possibilities and I want to clarify if this is what you are doing.

Comment: As for moving the debug forward - do you know what statement in the Lambda is generating the error message?  If the message is coming from Redshift the statements it sees will be logged in system tables (but only kept for a few days).

Comment: Hello again, from the lambda a process is called:
"call model.refresh_all_stores()";, and this process, in redshift, is declared with 5 redshift processes:
"call integration.stores_EU()";
"call integration.stores_USA ()"; etc

Comment: Sorry but those calls look to be specific to your code.  Can you get deeper in and find the action to the database that is producing the error?